# writeWorkSheet function in R not pasting values into Excel

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I am trying to copy some data from an R data frame (`Shipments`) to an excel file using `writeWorkBook` function in the `XLConnect` package. However, it is not copying anything to the excel file. The execution doesn't result in any error/warning appearing in the console. It just doesn't copy.

I have loaded the library XLConnect and made sure I am not loading the library xlsx. The column to be copied has been type-casted to dataframe as I thought that might be an issue.

`wbnames` is an additional thing. I directly wrote the sheet name in the writeWorkBook and it should have worked fine. Even with `wbnames` there hasn't been any change in the result.

I originally intended to copy the content to a macro file and then run the macro file from R itself but it wasn't working. So I thought it may be because of macro file but the function is not working on .xlsx itself.

So, not sure what is the issue. Would be grateful if I can get some help here. Am I missing something?

```
library(XLConnect) 
library(RDCOMClient) 

xlApp   <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk   <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(FILEPATH+FILENAME.XLSX)
xlWb    <- loadWorkbook(FILEPATH+FILENAME.XLSX)
wbnames <- as.vector(getSheets(xlWb))

# Copy a column from the existing data frame and paste it to the first
# sheet of the FILENAME.XLSX, starting at Row#6, no headers and no rownames:
writeWorksheet(xlWb, as.data.frame(Shipments$SHIPMENT_ID),
    sheet = wbnames[1], startRow = 6, header = F, rownames = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`xlWb` is the R-object that contains the workbook. It looks like the data has been written to the workbook, which is good. In order to view in Excel format, however, you still need to save the workbook to Excel. Add this line after your code and you should see a document called `your_file_name.xlsx` with your data in your working directory:

```
XLConnect::saveWorkbook(xlWb, "your_file_name.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'm relatively new to R. My mistake - treated steps like VBA debug mode where we see results right away after the execution of the step.